# Angular Expression with multiple fields

Tags: angularjs

The title may not be right but here is what I want to happen.

I have this code here:

```
`{{cost.cost_a}}`
```

and

```
`{{cost.cost_b}}`
```

Both have values, I want it so that if only one has a value then  it shows cost_b otherwise shows cost_a.

I was wondering if it would be an `ng-if` statement but I am unsure as to how this would work.

Sorry if i havent explained this correctly, If cost A has a value of 0 then show cost b otherwise show cost A

Comment: I think you need to provide a programming example to show what you mean - the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best way to do this is to have an expression that lives in your controller determining whether or not to show `cost_a` or `cost_b`.

```
// controller function
$scope.costDisplay = function costDisplayFn() {
  return cost.cost_b || cost.cost_a) ? cost.cost_b : cost.cost_a;
}
```

You can use this in your html to determine what displays.

```
<div>
 {{costDisplay()}}
</div>
```

This will keep the logic out of your DOM and in your controller where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `{{cost.cost_a || cost.cost_b}}`

Comment: Sorry might not have been clear with my explanation, I only need cost a to show if cost a has a number inside which is greater than 0. If i has a number than = 0 then show cost b

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous comment, you can achieve the result by modifying Gudz Daniel's answer as

```
{{(cost.cost_a > 0) ? cost.cost_a : cost.cost_b}}
```